# How do I specify a file type filter in plyer so that the user is only allowed to select files with certain extenions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for something like `filters = "*extension"`:

```py
Chosen_File = filechooser.open_file(multiple="true", filters = "*.jpeg", "*.jpg")
```

I tried this, but it does not work: I can still select files with extensions other than jpeg and jpg.

Comment: Hello, could you explain a bit more about your problem and the expected output you are looking to ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```py
Chosen_File = filechooser.open_file(multiple=TRUE, filters = ["*.jpeg", "*.jpg"])
```